# SSL broken with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and Matlab

Tags: .net, docker, matlab, ssl, shared-libraries

I am using [Matlab Compiler SDK](https://it.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/dotnet/create-a-dotnet-core-application-that-runs-on-linux-and-macos.html) to compile some Matlab code to .net DLL that I use as a dependency in a dotnet code 5 project.
The project is running inside a [AWS Docker image for writing Lambda in dotnet 5](https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet).

MathWorks documentation points out that setting the env var `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is key for this functionality to work.
What breaks is that I can't anymore make request to https end points with self signed certificates (all AWS services DynamoDB, S3, etc...).
The problem disappears as I take out the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with Matlab libraries, but of course when I do that Matlab binaries don't work anymore.
I have been reading articles [like this one](https://www.bswen.com/2018/11/others-Openssl-version-cause-error-when-loading-shared-libraries-libssl.so.1.1.html), and yet I didn't manage to fix this SSL issue, that of course I can bypass but I don't intend to.

**.net exception**

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The
> remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

> INNER EXCEPTION: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in > the certificate chain: PartialChain

I found out that the specific libraries that is causing this exception are:

- /opt/mcr/v99/bin/glnxa64/libssl.so.1.1
- /opt/mcr/v99/bin/glnxa64/libssl.so.1
- /opt/mcr/v99/bin/glnxa64/libcrypto.so.1.1
- /opt/mcr/v99/bin/glnxa64/libcrypto.so.1

They are provided by Matlab Runtime and linked through the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
I have tried to remove those and link the system one and in this way I **fix** the SSL issue, but I **break** Matlab execution.

**Useful articles**

- https://it.mathworks.com/support/search.html/answers/513449-what-unable-to-launch-the-matlabwindow-application-during-installation.html?fq=asset_type_name:answer%20category:support/introduct1740&page=1
- https://www.bswen.com/2018/11/others-Openssl-version-cause-error-when-loading-shared-libraries-libssl.so.1.1.html
- https://itectec.com/matlab/matlab-how-to-configure-matlab-to-allow-access-to-self-signed-https-servers/

Comment: “DLL” and “LD_LIBRARY_PATH” don’t belong in the same question. Maybe you can clarify what platform you’re on (looks like Linux, but “DLL”?) and which different SSL libraries you have on your path.

Comment: Hi, yes I am on Linux (Docker) and DLL dependencies for dotnet core are the normality. In fact Matlab Compiler SDK is a tool for creating such "universal" DLL. https://it.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/dotnet/create-a-dotnet-core-application-that-runs-on-linux-and-macos.html I'll add more details about the files in the path.

Comment: I don’t understand. Is this somehow running Windows DLL binaries on Linux? Sigh...

Comment: This is the whole point of dotnet core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid solution was written in this post: https://www.scivision.dev/matlab-websave-ssl-certificate/

It's useful to connect into the Docker image and check what you have in your `/etc/ssl/certs/*.srt`.
I solved my problem by adding the `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable that references the file:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

And now I have Matlab running on Docker Lambda.